# Potential memory leak in ARC enabled project while loading friends for fb

Tags: ios, facebook, memory-leaks

I'm getting memory leak while loading friend for fb, what could be the reason? I'm solving this error since last 3 days, but not able to find any strong reason.. :(

I do know very well that

```
"ARC only deals with Cocoa objects. If you are using Core Foundation objects you still have to use memory management. There are rules for transferring ownership of objects when using toll-free bridging. ARC doesn't make memory management go away - it just makes the more common parts of it easier and more efficient. So, yes - you still need to check for leaks."
```

Is there any Core Foundation objects in my code? if yes, how to manage it?

Checkout the image attached

[image]

Any help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

You have a **POTENTIALLY LEAK**, which means that maybe you have it or maybe you don't. Profiler can give false positive results. But just to be sure check the project with Instruments and verify the memory allocation (leaks). That will tell you for sure if you have a leak or not.